# Build apache ignite with netbeans ide

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, ignite

I want to build [apache ignite](https://github.com/MajidSalimi/ignite) source code with NetBeans IDE 8.2 and maven 3.3.9 in ubuntu 16.04 but when I build it, it encounters the following error:

```
   Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:flatten-maven-plugin:1.0.1:flatten (flatten) on project ignite-tools: The plugin org.codehaus.mojo:flatten-maven-plugin:1.0.1 requires Maven version 3.2.5 -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginIncompatibleException

After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
  mvn <goals> -rf :ignite-tools
```

and it is stopped with failure on the "Ignite tools" step.

It is normally built with the terminal command, but I need to build it with IDE.

I've already modified the Maven version, but the same error still appeared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just checked: You need to supply updated Maven to Netbeans instead of built-in version.

You have to go `Tools` -> `Options` -> `Java` pane -> `Maven` tab.

`Maven Home: Browse...`, choose your own downloaded Maven version directory, since built-in 3.0.2 < 3.2.5. You will have to download a fresh Maven install, I assume you already did.

You also need to choose `[x] Skip tests for builds not related to testing`, otherwise Apache Ignite will not build for you (running all tests takes 24h or so).

Then you can do `Run` -> `Clean and Build Project`, it will build all right.